# Word Documents Exported from SQL Server Reporting Services 2012 are Not Searchable

Tags: docx, ssrs-2012

How to reproduce...

1. Run SQL 2012 SP2
2. Create a blank report in SQL 2012 Reporting Services (SSRS 2012)
3. Add a text box with some text
4. Save and Run the report
5. Export to DOCX format
6. Save file to a local directory
7. Open the directory in Windows Explorer and search for any text
8. List item

Opening the file in Word 2013 launches Word in [Compatibility Mode].  You can save the file over top of itself which shows a window stating "Your document will be upgraded to the newest file format".  Completing this makes the document searchable but isn't really acceptable.
[image: Resave DOCX]

At first glance I am thinking SSRS is doing one of two things.  It is saving as an older version of DOCX (maybe Word 2007).  Or the file isn't quite right perhaps having a problem with the header/footer (pure speculation here).

So I need a solution that will either...
...fix the file and export it correctly so that we may search on it
...or be able to resave the Word files in with a batch program that resaves hundreds of DOCX files on a schedule.

Comment: Update: I opened this issue with Microsoft "Professional" support.  For over 2 months they kept preaching "This is by Design".  I refused to accept this and really beat them up verbally on the phone.  Eventually they moved this issue over to their Premier support team.  They have since acknowledged this and are busy finding out the reason why and if the problem is with SSRS or with Search/Indexing.  More to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hotfix for this issue has been released on the office update

3039756 April 5, 2016, update for Office 2013 (KB3039756)
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3039756/EN-US

Comment: The Microsoft Premier support team made good on their promise.  I am still annoyed that Microsoft professional support team is so bad!  It took 3 months for "Professional" support to create a "Premier" support ticket.  By comparison it took "Premier" support only 2 months to issue the patch.